# Individual assignments in Google Classroom API

Tags: google-classroom

Will the functional for creating individual assignments be available in API as well as in UI?

Answer (score 0):

Google classroom does provide API for creating assignments. [See its document.](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/create)

Comment: yes, but it provides creating assignments for a group, not for an individual student. UI Google Classroom has functional for selecting students from a list